# Adding simultaneous rates

Tags: arithmetic

If I have 3 rates like units/second produced by 3 separate devices and I want to get the total rate, is it ok to add the 3 rates up?
This seems basic and I'd say it's correct but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you are correct.**  (In normal conditions.)

That is, if you're given a problem like:

> Worker $A$ makes $5 \frac{\text{widgets}}{\text{hour}}$, worker $B$ makes $2 \frac{\text{widgets}}{\text{hour}}$, and worker $C$ makes $3 \frac{\text{widgets}}{\text{hour}}$.  What is the total rate?

The total rate is the sum of the other rates; in this case $10 \frac{\text{widgets}}{\text{hour}}$.

**However,** if the rates were dependent on each other (e.g. only one worker can use a certain tool at a time), then the problem becomes a bit more difficult, and no "one-size-fits-all" approach exists.